# Why isn't my Javascript Ajax call posting values to my PHP script?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, http-post

This is a very strange issue. The Javascript *IS* calling the PHP script, and the PHP script *IS* returning "something" (it returns `array ()`). The issue is, when I try to get the value of the posted data via `$_POST['ID']` it basically says that there is no posted value, even though `sendData` does contain a value for `ID`. The full string of `sendData` (obtained through `alert(sendData)`) is as follows:

`ID='1'&Invoice=''&FirstName=''&LastName=''&Description=''&Testimonial=''&ScreenRoom='false'&GlassWindow='true'`

**Javascript File:** admin.js

```
function saveChanges() {
    var sendData='ID=\'' + document.getElementById("ID").value + '\'';
    sendData+='&Invoice=\'' + document.getElementById("Invoice").value + '\'';
    sendData+='&FirstName=\'' + document.getElementById("FirstName").value + '\'';
    sendData+='&LastName=\'' + document.getElementById("LastName").value + '\'';
    sendData+='&Description=\'' + document.getElementById("Description").value + '\'';
    sendData+='&Testimonial=\'' + document.getElementById("Testimonial").value + '\'';
    sendData+='&ScreenRoom=\'' + document.getElementById("ScreenRoom").checked + '\'';
    sendData+='&GlassWindow=\'' + document.getElementById("GlassWindow").checked + '\'';
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("POST","scripts/saveChanges.php",true);  //true indicates ASYNCHRONOUS
    req.send(sendData);
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
      //Is request finished? Does the requested page exist?
        if(req.readyState==4 && req.status==200) {   
            //Your HTML arrives here
            alert(sendData);
            alert(req.responseText);
        }
    }
}
```

**PHP File (that is being posted to):** saveChanges.php (located in /scripts/)

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['group']) || $_SESSION['group'] != 'admin') {
    die ('You do not have permission to access this page!');
}
print_r($_POST);

$ID=$_POST['ID'];
$Invoice=$_POST['Invoice'];
$FirstName=$_POST['FirstName'];
$LastName=$_POST['LastName'];
$Description=$_POST['Description'];
$Testimonial=$_POST['Testimonial'];
$Date=$_POST['Date'];
$GlassWindow=$_POST['GlassWindow'];
$ScreenRoom=$_POST['ScreenRoom'];


?>
```

I normally only come here in a state of desperation, and being I've spent about 3 hours now working on trying to figure this out, I consider myself fairly desperate. Any help would be greatly appreciated and please ask if you need more information.

Comment: So for one: output of `array()` you have also, when *nothing* is received...looking! Ah, you say, `saveChanges.php  (located in /scripts/)`, when you make a call from javascript `scripts/saveChanges.php` it is relative to the directory you are in, do you get any errors in the `console`? Perhaps you try `/scripts/saveChanges.php`?

Comment: It is properly connecting to the php script, as I have added `echo 'test'` at the beginning of saveChanges.php and it has returned that in the alert.

Comment: I am confused, in which alert? What does the `alert(req.responseText);` actually say? Did you do the changes from @Musa?

Comment: Yes, i followed the changes @Musa suggested and they worked. Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the content type for php to read the variables

```
req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

Remove the quotes from the posted data and properly encode it

```
var sendData='ID=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("ID").value);
sendData+='&Invoice=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("Invoice").value);
sendData+='&FirstName=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("FirstName").value);
sendData+='&LastName=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("LastName").value);
sendData+='&Description=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("Description").value);
sendData+='&Testimonial=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("Testimonial").value);
sendData+='&ScreenRoom=' + document.getElementById("ScreenRoom").checked;
sendData+='&GlassWindow=' + document.getElementById("GlassWindow").checked;
```

Set the ready state listener before you send the request

```
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
  //Is request finished? Does the requested page exist?
    if(req.readyState==4 && req.status==200) {   
        //Your HTML arrives here
        alert(sendData);
        alert(req.responseText);
    }
}
req.send(sendData);
```

Comment: I changed my code as you stated as well as placing `req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');` before my ready state listener. To my surprise, the two alerts inside of the ready state listener do not even occur anymore. I'm beginning to think that this may be a specific issue with my website. Do you have any other thoughts? I have visited the website that is being called (http://www.bellasaluminum.com/scripts/saveChanges.php) and all permissions/.htaccess are set up properly.

Comment: I moved the setRequestHeader below the ready state listener and it worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set HTTP header:

```
req.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```